# Should a component commit a mutation directly?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

In the [Mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) chapter, you can see an example that uses mapMutations to map mutations to component methods.

It also says that

> You can commit mutations in components with this.$store.commit('xxx')

So the question comes, is committing a mutation directly from a component (not through an action) fine in vuex?

If it is, then this diagram may need to update:

[image]

Should I keep using the mapMutations method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it bad to commit mutations without using actions in Vuex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661956/is-it-bad-to-commit-mutations-without-using-actions-in-vuex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understood, *actions* are mainly used for asynchronous operations which might comprise multiple *mutations*. So yes, it's ok to directly use mutations, that's what they are made for. Only when you have more complex workflows involving multiple mutations you should wrap them in an action.

Answer (score 0):

`MapMuation` is just a helper that lets you use your defined mutations (in mutation-types) as methods of your component. It is exactly the same with `$store.commit` but with an easier notation.

I don't know in which context your diagram is but mutations can be called from everywhere (components, services, actions, getters etc...) en will do its work finely by synchronously updating the store.