# Vuex: Skipping Action and committing Mutation directly from Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

In vue.js app, using vuex as state management store, I need to simply change the value of a property in vuex. For this I can follow two methods:

1. Dispatch an `action` method, which will further commit `mutation`, which eventually will change the state.
2. The second method is to commit the `mutation` directly from the component and the mutation method will then change the state.

Currently, I'm using first method like this:

**In Component:**

`this.$store.dispatch('updateNotice', 'This is some notice')`

**In Actions:**

`updateNotice ({state, getters, commit}, payload) {
   commit('UPDATE_NOTICE', payload)
 }`

**In Mutations:**

`UPDATE_NOTICE (state, payload) {
   state.notice = payload
}`

As you might have noticed, I'm using the `action` method simply to commit a *single* mutation, without any other logic or *async* functionality.

My question is, in this case, should I not directly commit the mutation from the component itself? What is the best practice? Since using `action` method in this simple case seems verbose and serve no specific purpose.

Is there any reason that I should always `commit` actions from a component?
 Afterall, in vuex the `...mapMutations()` have some reason to exist.

Comment: I use mutations (and actions when needed) directly in components, because with "actions-only" i add a layer that is not needed and has to be read.

Comment: No reason not to use mutation directly in case like this. There is a section called `Committing Mutations in Components` in [official Vuex doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html). It's expected to commit mutation directly in component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it bad to commit mutations without using actions in Vuex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661956/is-it-bad-to-commit-mutations-without-using-actions-in-vuex)

Comment: Further details can also be found here: 
https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/587

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In your case it should be fine to commit the mutations directly in your components using `...mapMutations` or `$store` instance.

Since you asked the best practice, The primary reason for the existence of Actions is Asynchronicity. Mutations cannot be asynchronous whereas Actions can be, while you can call `$store.commit` directly in a Component this will be a synchronous event, but when you call `dispatch` the commit can be handled asynchronously within the action block unlike Mutations.

So the best practice is to use Actions to commit modifications to your state when it has to be handled asynchronously say you need to do an API call before committing the state change in such cases it would be a good idea to use Actions.